# How to automatic decode Dto from GET query parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot

I Have a GET request with some parameters which I handle as an object on the controller, consider it could be several parameters.

The problem is that the values for the properties on the dto are being filled using url encoding which I dont want because it messes up queries to a database later on, ie.: name gets populated with "some%20name" instead of "some name" as I would expect.

How can I avoid this encoding problem?

Bellow is a small scenario that represents my issue:

```
public class SomeDto {

    private String name;

    private String hex;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getHex() {
        return hex;
    }

    public void setHex(String hex) {
        this.hex = hex;
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("example")
public class RestController {

    @GetMapping
    public void example(final SomeDto someDto) {
        System.out.println(someDto.getName());
        System.out.println(someDto.getHex());
    }
}
```

```
public class ClientApi {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private String hostUri;

    public ClientApi(RestTemplate restTemplate, String hostUri) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.hostUri = hostUri;
    }

    public void test(SomeDto someDto) {
        var uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(hostUri + "/example");
        if(someDto != null) {
            uri.queryParam("name", someDto.getName())
               .queryParam("hex", someDto.getHex());
        }

        restTemplate.exchange(uri.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, null, Void.class);
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = DemoApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
class ClientApiTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private String port;

    private ClientApi clientApi;

    @BeforeEach
    void before() {
        clientApi = new ClientApi(new RestTemplate(), "http://localhost:" + port);
    }

    @Test
    void testMethod() {
        SomeDto someDto = new SomeDto();
        someDto.setName("some name");
        someDto.setHex("#ffffff");
        clientApi.test(someDto);
    }

}
```

UPDATE:
I was able to partially fix it by decoding the URL, however it only fixes name "some name" to reach the controller correctly, hex "#ffffff" on the other hand reaches as null.

```
var decodedUri = URLDecoder.decode(uri.toUriString(), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Comment: sorry and where is the problem with the example you are providing? I mean practically, what's the problem with the test? what's going wrong? What you would like to happen?

Comment: What I get on the controller is "some%20name" instead of "some name". That's what I'd like to fix somehow.

Comment: but in which controller? you are posting a test with `/test` endpoint, but the controller you are posting maps to another endpoint

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake, it is the same controller as the example. The endpoint is fixed now. Also I found that decoding the url before sending the request fixes the space issue but has side effects on other characters like #, probably because # indicates a url fragment which should not be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses some symbols as service symbols.

E.g. you cannot parse param value if it contains a comma.

`?someParam=some,value`

Would be parsed as two params: `some` and `value`. But if receive type is not array or collection then the second value will be ignored. Hence, you'll get `someParam=some`.

**The simplest way to avoid it is URL params base64 encoding**.

For me, the convenient way was to encode params as json in Base64.

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "hex": "fffffff"
}
```

Why json? Because there are many ready-made solutions for parsing JSON into an object.

So, your controller will receive Base64 value which is `eyJuYW1lIjoic29tZSBuYW1lIiwgImhleCI6ImZmZmZmZmYifQ==`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Objects;

@RestController
public class RestController {

    @GetMapping("/example")
    public void example(String params) {
        String decoded = decodeBase64(params);
        SomeDto dto = parseTo(decodedFilters, SomeDto.class);
    }

  public String decodeBase64(String encoded) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(encoded)) {
      return new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded));
    }
    return "";
  }

  public <T> T parseTo(String jsonAsString, Class<T> classType) {
    String toParse = Objects.nonNull(jsonAsString) ? jsonAsString : "{}";
    try {
      return new ObjectMapper().readValue(toParse, classType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new ValidationException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if that solution fits my situation. I am receiving the information through the url which somehow gets parsed automatically to a dto instance. There should be a way to configure this automatic deserialization to decode the params on parse.